# How to compare two occurrences within a text file using PHP?

Tags: php, text, compare

I've got a form in which users submit a radius for a circle. The area is worked out and posted back to them on a success page.

This occurs for several shapes. How would I now take these areas but for every `Circle` on the text file and compare it against every area for the `Square` then for example do a query such as "which shape type has a greater total area combined: 'shape name here'"?

The reason for no code is because I don't even know where to begin! The text file has the following layout:

```
Triangle,Red,12,12,12,12
Triangle,Red,12,12,12,12
Triangle,Red,12,12,12,12
Circle,Red,2134
Triangle,Green,10,20,5,6
Circle,Red,120
Triangle,Green,10,20,30,40
Circle,Blue,120
Square,Red,120
Circle,Red,123
Circle,Red,123
```

Comment: How does the text file look like? Just a space-delimited list of radiuses?

Comment: @mirelon refer to main post

Comment: So you want to calculate total area of all instances of a shape, with respect to overlaps?

Comment: @mirelon It already calculates the area of each individual input, i want it so now it adds up all the areas for a shape like 'circle' then compare it to the total of all total areas of 'square'.

Comment: I was a bit confused with those numbers... why the triangle has 4 numbers and not only 3?

Comment: @mirelon because it takes into account the triangles height

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a function named area:

```
function area($shape, $params) {
  // do your calculations
}
```

We will have an associative array `$total` that will hold data like `'Triangle' => 47`

```
$s = file_get_contents("input.txt");

foreach(explode("\n", $s) as $line) {
  $parts = explode(",", $line);
  $shape = $parts[0];
  $params = array_slice($parts, 2);
  $total[$shape] += area($shape, $params);
}
arsort($total); // reverse sort the array by the total area
reset($total); // needed for key() to point to the first item
echo key($total); // echo the shape with the largest area
```